# CloudSQLへプライベートIPで接続したいが出来ない

Tags: mysql, sql, network, database, google-cloud

[teratailでも同様の質問をしています](https://teratail.com/questions/kuq2z8wkb4lutk)が、こちらでも質問させて頂きます。
よろしくお願い致します。

## 質問

GCPのCloudSQLでDBを構築しています。
DBにパブリックIPを付与して外部から接続することは出来るのですが、
レイテンシを高めたいのとセキュリティの観点から、プライベートIPで接続するように変更したいと考えています。
しかし、プライベートIPを付与してCloudSQLを構築しても接続が出来ず、何の設定が足りていないのか分からず詰まっています。
他に何か設定が必要なのでしょうか。ご教示いただけると幸いです。

## 試したこと

・パブリックIPのCloudSQLを構築(承認済みネットワークには0.0.0.0/0を追加済み)し外部から接続できることを確認
・同じ設定でプライベートIPでCloudSQLを構築
・プライベートIPでCloudSQLが立ち上がった事を確認(10.系のIPが付与されている事を確認)
・同じVPC内のGCEからCloudSQLのプライベートIPにmysqlコマンドで接続しようとしたり、pingコマンドを飛ばしても応答無し。

## 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

MySQL 8.0
シングルゾーン

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCEとCloudSQLを0から再作成してみたところ繋がるようになりました！